# Error while attempting to create a stream to listen to changes in Firebase database (flutter)

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am uploading pictures to Firebase Storage and then saving the link into Firebase Database.
And I created a stream to listen for changes in the database so every time there's a new image uploaded it will be shown in the app.

But every time I run the app it gives me an error, and the app crashes.
(As seen here: https://prnt.sc/txj3jc).

Flutter doctor: https://prnt.sc/txj5q8.

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
int pictureNumber = 0;
List<Widget> pictures = [];

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String imageLink;
  File _image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 30,
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          _image =
              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

          FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
          StorageReference rootReference = firebaseStorage.ref();
          StorageReference pictureFolderRef =
              rootReference.child('pictures').child('$pictureNumber');
          pictureFolderRef.putFile(_image).onComplete.then((storageTask) async {
            String link = await storageTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
            await _firestore
                .collection('links')
                .add({'link': link, 'index': pictureNumber});
            setState(() {
              pictures.add(Image.network('$link'));
              print(link);
              _firestore.collection('links').orderBy('index');
            });
            pictureNumber++;
//            setState(() {
//              imageLink = link;
//              pictures.add(
//                Image.network('$imageLink'),
//              );
//              print(pictures.length);
//            });
          });
        },
      ),
//      body: Container(
//        width: double.infinity,
//        child: Column(
//          children: [
//            Expanded(
//                child: ListView.builder(
//              itemCount: pictures.length,
//              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
//                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
//                child: pictures[index],
//              ),
//            )),
//          ],
//        ),
//      ),
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    body: PictureStream(),
    );
  }
}

class PictureStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _firestore.collection('links').snapshots(),
      // ignore: missing_return
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3E3E3E),
            ),
          );
        }
        final links = snapshot.data;
        for (var linkData in links) {
          final index = linkData.data['index'];
          final link = linkData.data['link'];

          pictures.add(Image.network(link));
        }
        return Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: pictures.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: pictures[index],
                ),
              )),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device SM A205F...
Restarted application in 3,046ms.
D/SurfaceView( 8984): onWindowVisibilityChanged(4) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{99c7814 V.E...... ........ 0,0-720,1560} of ViewRootImpl@c270626[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@c270626[MainActivity]( 8984): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,720,1560) new=(0,0,720,1560) req=(720,1560)4 dur=11 res=0x1 s={false 0} ch=false
D/ViewRootImpl@c270626[MainActivity]( 8984): stopped(false) old=true
D/SurfaceView( 8984): windowStopped(false) false io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{99c7814 V.E...... ........ 0,0-720,1560} of ViewRootImpl@c270626[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@c270626[MainActivity]( 8984): stopped(false) old=false
D/SurfaceView( 8984): onWindowVisibilityChanged(0) true io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{99c7814 V.E...... ........ 0,0-720,1560} of ViewRootImpl@c270626[MainActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@c270626[MainActivity]( 8984): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,720,1560) new=(0,0,720,1560) req=(720,1560)0 dur=15 res=0x7 s={true 515117469696} ch=true
D/OpenGLRenderer( 8984): createReliableSurface : 0x77f381c840, 0x77ef64d000
D/mali_winsys( 8984): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/SurfaceView( 8984): surfaceCreated 1 #8 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{99c7814 V.E...... ........ 0,0-720,1560}
D/mali_winsys( 8984): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/SurfaceView( 8984): surfaceChanged (720,1560) 1 #8 io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{99c7814 V.E...... ........ 0,0-720,1560}
D/ViewRootImpl@c270626[MainActivity]( 8984): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager( 8984): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@2fcf57c[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 8984): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager( 8984): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@2fcf57c[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 8984): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager( 8984): Starting input: tba=menachemmaron14082004.image_firebase ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager( 8984): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager( 8984): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
I/flutter ( 8984): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8984): The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 8984): _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#3e08b):
I/flutter ( 8984): type 'QuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
I/flutter ( 8984): 
I/flutter ( 8984): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 8984):   StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>
I/flutter ( 8984):   file:///C:/Users/menac/AndroidStudioProjects/image_firebase/lib/main.dart:99:12
I/flutter ( 8984): 
I/flutter ( 8984): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 8984): #0      PictureStream.build.<anonymous closure> (package:image_firebase/main.dart:111:30)
I/flutter ( 8984): #1      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:509:81)
I/flutter ( 8984): #2      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:127:48)
I/flutter ( 8984): #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4623:28)
I/flutter ( 8984): #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4506:15)
I/flutter ( 8984): #5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4679:11)
I/flutter ( 8984): #6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4222:5)
I/flutter ( 8984): #7      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2627:33)
I/flutter ( 8984): #8      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:864:20)
I/flutter ( 8984): #9      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5)
I/flutter ( 8984): #10     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1074:15)
I/flutter ( 8984): #11     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1013:9)
I/flutter ( 8984): #12     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:929:5)
I/flutter ( 8984): #16     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:277:10)
I/flutter ( 8984): #17     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:235:3)
I/flutter ( 8984): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter ( 8984): 
I/flutter ( 8984): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#3e08b):
type 'QuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> file:///C:/Users/menac/AndroidStudioProjects/image_firebase/lib/main.dart:99:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PictureStream.build.<anonymous closure> (package:image_firebase/main.dart:111:30)
#1      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:509:81)
#2      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:127:48)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4623:28)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4506:15)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
type 'QuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> file:///C:/Users/menac/AndroidStudioProjects/image_firebase/lib/main.dart:99:12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I am new to Flutter, so sorry if it's a stupid mistake.

**EDIT:**
The first part of the question was solved, but now there is another problem, it shows every image multiple times instead of just once.

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
int pictureNumber = 0;
List<Widget> pictures = [];

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String imageLink;
  File _image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 30,
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          _image =
              // ignore: deprecated_member_use
              await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

          FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
          StorageReference rootReference = firebaseStorage.ref();
          StorageReference pictureFolderRef =
              rootReference.child('pictures').child('$pictureNumber');
          pictureFolderRef.putFile(_image).onComplete.then((storageTask) async {
            String link = await storageTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
            await _firestore
                .collection('links')
                .add({'link': link, 'index': pictureNumber});
            setState(() {
              pictureNumber++;
              pictures.add(Image.network('$link'));
              print(link);
              _firestore.collection('links').orderBy('index');
            });
            print(pictures.length);
//            setState(() {
//              imageLink = link;
//              pictures.add(
//                Image.network('$imageLink'),
//              );
//              print(pictures.length);
//            });
          });
        },
      ),
//      body: Container(
//        width: double.infinity,
//        child: Column(
//          children: [
//            Expanded(
//                child: ListView.builder(
//              itemCount: pictures.length,
//              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
//                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
//                child: pictures[index],
//              ),
//            )),
//          ],
//        ),
//      ),
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: PictureStream(),
    );
  }
}

class PictureStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _firestore.collection('links').orderBy('link').snapshots(),
      // ignore: missing_return
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3E3E3E),
            ),
          );
        }
        final links = snapshot.data.documents;
        for (var linkData in links) {
          final index = linkData.data['index'];
          final link = linkData.data['link'];
          print(link);
          print(index);

          pictures.add(Image.network(link));
          print(pictures.length);
        }
        return Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: pictures.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: pictures[index],
                ),
              )),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Firebase storage - https://prnt.sc/txy8ag
Firebase Database - https://prnt.sc/txya16

It shows all 3 images in order by their index - 3 times, in total 9 images are shown on the app.

Answer (score 0):

What the error simply means is that you are treating `QuerySnapshot` object as if it's a `List`.

Comment: So how would one use the QuerySnapshot for the functionality I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here

```
final links = snapshot.data;
    for (var linkData in links) {
      final index = linkData.data['index'];
      final link = linkData.data['link'];

      pictures.add(Image.network(link));
    }
```

You can confirm by going to line 111 and col 30 since that’s where the error is. You should do `final links = snapshot.data.documents`. This will pass the `List` of `DocumentSnapshot` to `links`. You want to iterate on the documents instead of the `QuerySnapshot` itself. Remeber `snapshot`  is of type `AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>` so `snapshot.data` will return a `QuerySnapshot`. The `.documents` getter will then return a `List<DocumentSnapshot>` which are the results of the query.

Consider using strong typing while writing code to avoid problems lime this in the future.

Comment: I edited the question, since there is a new problem. I'll be more than happy if you could me with it as well.